# Does L293D consume power when not in use

Tags: pic, motor, integrated-circuit

I am designing a robot using the L293D motor driver, and I have just successfully hooked it up to my micro controller.  I am using two batteries, one two control the motor and one to control the pic micro.  I am wondering if the battery that is used to drive the motor would get consumed when the pic circuit is off.  I need to know this, because in my design i was considering directly connecting the motor supply to the driver without a switch.

Comment: As a matter of interest what current are you expecting to feed into the motor (under load) and what voltage supply is the L293D running from to power the motor. I know this sounds like an odd question but if you can answer I might be able to give other advice about choosing a better H bridge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does. Look at the [datasheet](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00000059.pdf) for the details. **Quiescent Current** is the spec you want to look at. It draws significant current from Vs as well as from Vss, even when Ven = L. (~30mA max), although it's important to consider the voltages. The 24mA(max) from the 5V rail (Iss) is 120mW, but the 4mA(max) from the 24V rail (Is) is almost as much power (96mW).

[image]